# Design reason behind the relationship between element's property and its corresponding attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, properties

I'm puzzled by the reason behind how the relationship between some DOM element's `property` and its corresponding `attributes` works.

Below is a graph from the book `jquery in action 2015 Bear Bibeault`, showing the relationship between `property` and `attribute` of DOM element.

[image]

To further explain the concept, the author had the following code and explanation for the code.

[image]

[image]

My question is, why some `property` and `attribute` are synced, why some are not synced, and why some `attributes` does not have corresponding `property`?

I have found a [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/5581182) explaining the relationship between `property` and `attribute`, but it didn't touch on why it was designed this way. I hope to understand the reasons behind the design.

A related question, if I want to get or set a value on a DOM element, should I get/set the `property` or the `attribute`?

And how do we find the relationship between a particular `property` and its corresponding `attribute` when we need to? Is there a documentation specifically detailing the relationship?

Comment: It mostly wasn't "designed" that way. It's the organic result of different decisions taken at different times by different people. Note that the second bullet point in the quote above is wrong. Whether a property is boolean or not does not determine whether there is a property and attribute of the same name that reflect one another. It's true that `checked` does not, but, for example, the boolean `autofocus` property and attribute on input elements do reflect one another. The `checked` attribute is instead reflected by the `defaultChecked` property.

Comment: @Alohci thanks for your comments. It just feels like the relationship between property and attributes is messy enough that it makes it very hard for beginner like me to make any sense of it. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the answers buried inside HTML specs. I first want you to have a look at the attributes and properties of the [`input` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-input-element) (heading "Content attributes" and "DOM interface") and the section about [attribute reflection](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes) (first paragraph).

You will notice that **all attributes have corresponding properties** and manipulating a property will change the attribute it reflects. It is worth noting that:

(1) An attribute could be reflected by a property with a slightly different name. The classical example is the `class` attribute which is reflected by `className` property and `for` attribute which is reflected by `htmlFor` property.

(2) **Likewise the [`checked` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-checked) is reflected by [`defaultChecked` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-defaultchecked) whereas the [`checked` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-checked) represents the internal state of the checkbox irrespective of the `checked` attribute**. This has always caused confusion among programmers (and book authors). The difference is explained at the end of this answer.

(3) Made-up attributes (such as the "book" attribute in your example) will not generate corresponding property and vice-versa. For this purpose the HTML specs describe a mechanism called [data attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) and [`dataset` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-htmlelement-dataset).

> A related question, if I want to get or set a value on a DOM element,
>   should I get/set the `property` or the `attribute`?

Depends. For example both of the following produce identical result and HTML:

```
document.getElementById("div-1").title = "Hello";
document.getElementById("div-1").setAttribute("title") = "Hello";
```

However, for form elements you should manipulate the state instead of attribute. Suppose you have this HTML markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
```

And you execute either of the following:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-1").defaultChecked = true;
document.getElementById("checkbox-1").setAttribute("checked", "checked");
```

And here is the result:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" checked="checked">
```

But whether the checkbox actually get checked depends on the **dirtiness** of the control (i.e. if its state was changed at some point). For form elements you would normally manipulate the properties that correspond to the internal state:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-1").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 13):

DOM is something that has grown "naturally" to a large degree. You have to consider, HTML (meaning: attributes) came first and originally there was no scripting whatsoever. Eventually, Netscape introduced JavaScript with what you would consider an extremely limited API today. This API was geared towards manipulating forms, not really arbitrary HTML elements. And then Netscape and Internet Explorer came out with different variants of what they called DHTML back then (Dynamic HTML). Netscape's variant relied on a special `<layer>` tag and nobody remembers it today. The Internet Explorer variant allowed more generic access to HTML elements and in particular had a 1:1 mapping of attributes to properties.

While Internet Explorer won this war, its DHTML variant was designed when people were thinking of HTML attribute names as a fixed collection. With arbitrary attributes, it had too many issues. For example:

- The `class` attribute could not be mapped to JavaScript originally because `class` is a reserved keyword. While subsequent changes to the JavaScript standard allowed using reserved keywords as property names, Internet Explorer has to map `class` attribute to the `className` property. Setting `className` attribute on an element or `el["class"]` property on a JavaScript object resulted in hilarious inconsistencies.
- HTML attributes are case-insensitive whereas JavaScript properties are case-sensitive. So Internet Explorer had all kinds of hacks to recognize intent. What happened when the element was `<FOO SOMEATTIRIBUTE>` and you tried to access `el.someAttribute` or `el.SOMEATTRIBUTE` from JavaScript? I no longer remember, but it wasn't pretty.
- JavaScript objects always have methods as well. An attribute `toString` for example cannot possibly be mapped to a property because it would mask the `toString()` method.

No browser other than Internet Explorer ever implemented this 1:1 mapping of attributes to properties, and even Internet Explorer gave up on it as soon as it was feasible in terms of backwards compatibility (this took a very long time). Instead, attributes and properties are treated as separate namespaces now. Browsers will provide you with some properties as shortcuts for attribute access and manipulation, but they are really only there for your convenience. And there are some backwards compatibility cases muddying the waters: the `value` property and `value` attribute are not actually mapped to each other, the former reflecting the current state of the element whereas the latter reflects its initial state.

**Edit**: Just for reference, you are quoting the following statement:

> If attribute exists as a built-in property but it's a Boolean, the value isn't synchronized.

This is wrong, the behavior has nothing to do with booleans vs. strings. As mentioned above, the `value` property is similarly missing synchronization as the `checked` property. On the other hand, the boolean `hidden` property will be synced with the corresponding attribute properly. From what I can tell, you will find missing sync between property and attribute around the original form manipulation APIs that have been introduced by Netscape - this is simply backwards compatibility.

So maybe you shouldn't trust people who write books on jQuery with DOM questions. After all, these explicitly chose to quit touching the DOM directly and opted for an entirely different representation with its very own set of quirks.

Comment: thank you very much for the history lesson. Its good to know what happen in the past in order to understand the present. Do you mind if I ask, what do you think is the best way to deal with the inconsistencies? Should I only get/set attributes or something else? What's working for you, that can lesser the pain?

Comment: @Thor: The inconsistencies are few these days, learning where to expect them isn't hard. If in doubt, I'm always checking MDN documentation on the properties.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: The snarky comment at the end is unnecessary

Comment: @Alexander: Maybe. But at least judging by the excepts presented here, the book is largely responsible for the OP's confusion.